# Error: "New-ADUser : The object name has bad syntax"

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-5.0

I am creating a PowerShell script at work to copy user accounts.  The script works perfectly on my test Server 2016 VM. It also works in our work environment on a coworkers Windows 10 PC, however I cannot run it on my local machine.  It returns the following error:

```
New-ADUser : The object name has bad syntax
At line:155 char:1
+ New-ADUser -Name $New_DisplayName @params
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=cnelson test...ctions,DC=local:String) [New-ADUser], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8335,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser

Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: 'cnelsontest1' under:
'DC=,DC=local'.
At line:159 char:29
+ Add-ADGroupMember -Members $Username.Text
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (cnelsontest1:ADPrincipal) [Add-ADGroupMember], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SetADGroupMember.ValidateMembersParameter,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.AddADGroupMember
```

```
$params = @{'SamAccountName' = $Username.Text;
            'Instance' = $AD_Account_To_Copy;
            'DisplayName' = $New_DisplayName;
            'GivenName' = $FirstName.Text;
            'Path' = $New_Path;
            'SurName' = $LastName.Text;
            'ChangePasswordAtLogon' = $true;
            'Enabled' = $true;
            'UserPrincipalName' = $Username.Text;
            'AccountPassword' = $New_Pass;
            'EmailAddress' = $Username.Text + '@azcorrections.gov';
            'HomePage' = $HomePage.HomePage;
            'Description' = $NewDescription.Description;
            'Office' = $NewOffice.Office;
            'StreetAddress' = $NewStreet.StreetAddress;
            'City' = $NewCity.City;
            'State' = $NewState.State;
            'PostalCode' = $NewPostalCode.PostalCode;
            'Title' = $NewTitle.Title;
            'Department' = $NewDepartment.Department;
            'Company' = $NewCompany.Company;
            'ScriptPath' = $NewScript.ScriptPath;
            'OfficePhone' = $PhoneNumber.text;
            }

New-ADUser -Name $New_DisplayName @params
```

[Full Script link](https://pastebin.com/ugJ6u9St)

I'm running PSVersion 5.1.150

Any ideas as to what i'm missing and why i'm coming across this error?  I have no idea what it is referring to, nor why it works on one coworkers computer but not my own.

---

**Edit:** Value of `$params` at the time of the error:

```
Name                  Value
----                  -----
AccountPassword       System.Security.SecureString
Description           Chris Nelson Test Account
UserPrincipalName     cnelsontest1
HomePage              http://...
DisplayName           cnelson test1
SamAccountName        cnelsontest1
ScriptPath
EmailAddress          cnelsontest1@example.com
Office                test
GivenName             cnelson
Title                 SYSTEMS/LAN ADMR
Company
OfficePhone           555-1234
StreetAddress         Sesame Street
PostalCode            54321
SurName               test1
State                 candid
Department            IT
ChangePasswordAtLogon True
Path                   cnelson,OU=IT_TECHSRVS,OU=Information Technology,OU=ADMIN,OU=CENT_OFF,DC=example,DC=com
City                  
Enabled               True
Instance              CN=test\, cnelson,OU=IT_TECHSRVS,OU=Information Technology,OU=ADMIN,OU=CENT_OFF,DC=example,DC=com
```

I'm calculating `$New_Path` like this:

```
$New_Path = (Get-ADUser ($UsernameCopy.Text)).DistinguishedName -replace '^.*?,', ''
```

Comment: Try adding the `Name` to your params `'Name' = $New_DisplayName;` and then calling with just splatting: `New-ADUser @params`

Comment: `try { New-ADUser ... } catch { $params }`. Make sure all parameters have the value you expect them to have.

Comment: @JamesC. That shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers how exactly do i type that in to test your idea?  I apologize if this is a silly question.  Do I just surround the `New-ADUser` part in brackets and add `catch { $params }` at the end?

Comment: @cnelson Don't forget the `try` at the beginning.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers when i changed line to `try { New-ADUser -Name $New_DisplayName } catch { @params }` it gave me an error of:    
  
`+ try { New-ADUser -Name $New_DisplayName } catch { @params }
+                                                 ~~~~~~~
The splatting operator '@' cannot be used to reference variables in an expression. '@params' can be used only as an argument to a command. To 
reference variables in an expression use '$params'.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SplattingNotPermitted`

Comment: Please read carefully: `... catch { $params }`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers You are correct, i misread that.  However, i think in order to fully test that I need to pull the code out of the form script as it didn't show me anything after i ran it except that it couldn't find the new user account to copy the group memberships into, it didn't show the bad syntax error, but also didn't show anything else.

Comment: If you're running the code from a form try writing it to a file (`$params | Out-String | Set-Content 'C:\path\to\params.txt'`) or displaying it with a message box (`[Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show(($params | Out-String))`).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers here is the output: https://pastebin.com/Qb2yAnkF  

it looks to me like the path and the instance aren't matching up.  Thoughts?

Comment: Looks like you used a split operation or an insufficiently specific regexp replacement for calculating `$Path` from `$AD_Account_To_Copy`. Please show the code where you do *that*. The code and error you posted is just a symptom.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers here is the code i used as requested.  

`(Get-ADUser ($UsernameCopy.Text)).DistinguishedName -replace '^.*?,',''`

https://pastebin.com/CMhs76Qz      Here is the full script code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you remove the common name portion from the value of `$AD_Account_To_Copy` is flawed. `-replace '^.*?,', ''` will remove everything up to the first comma in the string. If the common name itself contains a comma (like in `CN=test\, cnelson,OU=...`) the replacement won't remove `cnelson,`. Amend your regular expression with a positive lookahead assertion, so that everything before the first `OU=` is removed:

```
$New_Path = $AD_Account_To_Copy -replace '^.*?,\s*(?=ou=)', ''
```

Comment: @AnsgarWichers I changed the line in question to:  
`$New_Path = (Get-ADUser ($UsernameCopy.Text)).DistinguishedName -replace '^.*?,\s*(?=ou=)', ''' and am getting a whole new set of errors.  

[New Error Messages](https://pastebin.com/cCD6K1tB)